# Kendo grid how to catch cell change event

Tags: events, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, onchange

I need to trigger the change event if i change text in predefined cell.

I need something like this:

```
{   field: "username",
    title : $translate.instant('USER_NAME'),
    onchange:function(value) {
      // HERE I NEED TO GET CHANGED TEXT
    }
},
```

How can i do it in Kendo UI?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please provide More information what text ? is it in Edit Mode ? if Edit mode what Edit Mode ? etc..

Comment: Yes, is it in inline edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  [Datasource Parameter Map](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) once you click update you can take the changed data and map it before its send to server

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    update: {
      url: "Test url",
      dataType: "json" 
    },
    parameterMap: function(data, type) {
      if (type == "update") {
         // data.models will have your updated Values 
        return { models: kendo.stringify(data.models) };

      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Update**

If you need to get the change event for cell attach a event handler to the cell if grid dataBound event

```
dataBound: function (e) {
    // index is what ever the column index you need
 $("#kgrid").find('table tr td:nth-child(index)').unbind("click").bind("click", function (e) {
          var dataItem = $("#kgrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));

 });

}
```

Comment: But i would like to trigger method after i leave cell.

Comment: @redrom i have updated the Answer , did not exactly test the cell select 'table tr td:nth-child(index)' select the cell you need and attach the handler and dataitem will have the row data from the datasource